# Python shell is restarted every time i do "run module" inside editor?

Tags: restart, python

I have simply the following in my editor:

```
def main ():
    print("hello!"); //Also tried print "hello"
```

Each time I do Run->"Run Module", the Python shell is restarted and nothing is printed

Comment: You defined a function but didn't call it.

Comment: you forgot to type `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`

Comment: Isn't main() the first function thats called?

Comment: nm, so I should include a main() near the bottom

Comment: Python is not C or Java; `main()` is not automatically called.

Answer (score 1):

In Python there's no default main behaviour, so what you usually want to do is following:

```
def main():
    # your code

if __name__ == "__main__":  # this means that the script was an argument for the interperet
    main()
```